# How do I import info from a database to my website?

Tags: php, mysql

Using the code below I am trying to import users table into my php page and only want to show the last ten entries in a table, what else do I need to add to my code to achieve this

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dispenses";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "Amount: " . $row["amount"];
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You would need to start by telling us what you are using, your question is general other wise. I would say that you need to use a query for starters, and maybe lead into something more complicated like a web service.

Comment: **A:** You would "Google it", as the cool kids say.

Comment: I am using this script here https://github.com/chipshotDEV/Faucet-Builder

Comment: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/phpmyadmin/import-database-using-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$query = "SELECT * FROM 'users'";

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "id: " . $row["id"];
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: If I am using http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp that code where would I place? 

$query = "SELECT * FROM 'users'";

Comment: That worked perfectly but it is showing  a lot of rows from the database, how do I limit it to 10 results only? @J Hock

Comment: Also it lists all entries, how would I show just the last 10 entries

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp